# "Does not match selector known to Objective C runtime" crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

can somebody help me with this crash?

Got this error message but don't have any clue what is it?

** *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x174a5c410) for message '\361\340L\265\241!' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime**

Next line:

**(null): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17106ca40**

Comment: Please share your code, (with line self.performselector(......)

Comment: actually don't use this method((

Comment: Please share your code with error line, so I can help you

Comment: Try to add All Exceptions breakpoint to help you find the cause.